# creating multidimensional array from single array

Tags: php

i have a html form in which i use array like this (name="courts[]"). when it send data to php file i use foreeach loop to create multidimensional array for inserting records in mysql. In php file i write foreeach loop to iterate like this

```
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($court_name as $result)
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'court_name' => $result[0]
        );
        $i++;
    }
```

it display result this

```
 Array
 (
      [0] => Array
       (
            [court_name] => P
       )

      [1] => Array
      (
           [court_name] => S
      )

 )
```

instead of this

```
 Array
 (
      [0] => Array
       (
            [court_name] => Punjab
       )

      [1] => Array
      (
           [court_name] => Sindh
      )

 )
```

Answer (score 2):

(referring the outputs) in your loop, `$result` contains court name. So if you use `$result[0]`, you get first character of string.

Try this:

```
foreach ($court_name as $result)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'court_name' => $result
    );
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach loop gives you one element of array (`$result`) now you access to the first character of value via `$result[0]`, change it to `$result`

```
foreach ($court_name as $result) {
  $data[] = array( 'court_name' => $result );
}
```